# Is there any way to Access azure key vault secret with logged in AD access token using c#?

Tags: c#, azure-keyvault, azure-ad-msal, azure-authentication

I have authenticated my windows app with azure AD , I have to get secret from azure key vault using logged in **AD user Access Token** , is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Yes, it is called delegated access. It requires setup in Azure and in code. Research it and come back if you have specific questions.